# Wordpress wp_get_attachment_thumb_url full

Tags: query-posts, post-thumbnails, attachments

My code in index: (show all attachment by one post ID)

```
<?php query_posts('p=1498'); if (have_posts()) { while (have_posts()) { the_post(); ?>

<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => -1, 'orderby' => 'rand', 'post_mime_type' => 'image' ,'post_status' => null, 'post_parent' => $post->ID ); 
$attachments = get_posts($args);
    if ($attachments) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $attachment->ID, $size = 'full' )?>" alt="<?php echo get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true) ?>" />
<?php }} ?>

<?php }} wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

but image src show it's: `thumbnail: http://www.mywebsite.vn/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/vcbf-150x80.jpg` ?

How to show image full as: `http://www.mywebsite.vn/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/vcbf.jpg`

Thanks

Comment: Just a note here, **never** use `query_posts`. It really breaks a lot of page functions. Rather use `WP_Query` which is also used by the main query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in the foreach loop:

```
$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
```

And this for the img src:

```
echo $thumb_url[0];
```

Comment: that's correct. have a great days!